# Unable to convert Redis.RedisValue to Task<T>

Tags: c#, .net, task-parallel-library, stackexchange.redis

I am trying to write a generic class/interface that will fetch data from Redis Cache. I have tried to make it generic because we have different type of data and it's difficult to write so many classes for each data type.

Here is my interface & class.

```
public interface IRedisCache<T>
{
    Task<T> GetValue(string code);
}

public class RedisCache<T> : IRedisCache<T>
{

    public RedisCache()
    {

    }

    public Task<T> GetValue(string code)
    {
        var cache = RedisConnectorHelper.Connection.GetDatabase();
        var value = cache.StringGet($"Device_Status:{code}");

        Task<T> myTask = (Task<T>)value;

        return myTask;
    }

}
```

I am facing problem in line:

```
Task<T> myTask = (Task<T>)value;
```

The problem is in converting Redis.RedisValue type to `Task<T>` type.

I am getting error message

> "Cannot convert `Redis.Redisvalue` type to `System.Threading.Tasks.Task<T>`"

I am using Stack Exchange.Redis library, with Dot Net core 2.

Comment: NKosi, no it is not. Thats why I posted the question. The title is "Unable to convert Redis.RedisValue to Task<T>".

Comment: What do you store and in what format?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming the value was originally stored as JSON in the cache,

```
cache.StringSet($"Device_Status:{code}", JsonConvert.SerializeObject(myObject)));
```

then just deserialize the returned value to the desired type

```
public async Task<T> GetValue(string code) {
    var cache = RedisConnectorHelper.Connection.GetDatabase();
    var value = await cache.StringGetAsync($"Device_Status:{code}");
    T resultFromCache = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(value);
    return resultFromCache;
}
```

I would suggest refactoring the cache service to

```
public interface IRedisCache {
    Task<T> GetValue<T>(string code);
}
```

With implementation using what was suggested above

```
public class RedisCache : IRedisCache {
    public async Task<T> GetValue<T>(string code) {
        var cache = RedisConnectorHelper.Connection.GetDatabase();
        var value = await cache.StringGetAsync($"Device_Status:{code}");
        T resultFromCache = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(value);
        return resultFromCache;
    }
}
```